# JavaFX Pane z-order

Tags: javafx-8

I'm starting a small high-performance charting library for JavaFX because supplied chart libraries are still buggy and were not designed to show huge amount of points (20k+).

My custom chart class was extending `StackPane`but this doesn't allow me to explicitly position elements as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118394/explicitly-positioning-nodes-in-javafx) and I had this issue. So now I moved to `Pane` but `Pane` doesn't seems to allow a z-order despite lot of people saying that z-order is implemented according to the `Node` position in the children list.

This is what I get when extending `StackPane`:

[image]

And this is when I use `Pane` instead:

[image]

As you can see the lines are not showed anymore. Here is how I add my nodes:

```
 private Pane chartBackground = new Pane();
    private Pane chartPlotPane = new Pane();
    private XYAxis xAxis = new XYAxis();
    private XYAxis yAxis = new XYAxis();

getChildren().addAll(chartBackground, xAxis, yAxis);
```

Where `XYAxis` are just the black lines. Here is the full code if you need it:

```
public class XYChart<X extends Number,Y extends Number> extends Pane{

    private ArrayList<XYSeries<X,Y>> seriesList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Components
    private Pane chartBackground = new Pane();
    private Pane chartPlotPane = new Pane();
    private XYAxis xAxis = new XYAxis();
    private XYAxis yAxis = new XYAxis();

    // Properties
    private Color BG_COLOR = Color.valueOf("EDEDED");
    private Color PLOT_PANE_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private double yPadding = 20, xPadding = 20;

    public XYChart(){
        getChildren().addAll(chartBackground, xAxis, yAxis);

        chartBackground.setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + BG_COLOR.toString().substring(2) + ";");
        chartPlotPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + PLOT_PANE_COLOR.toString().substring(2) + ";");
        chartPlotPane.setMouseTransparent(true);

        setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            chartPlotPane.setLayoutX(event.getSceneX());
            chartPlotPane.setLayoutY(event.getSceneY());

            System.out.println("Drag x: " + event.getX());
        });

        redraw();
    }

    public void addSeries(XYSeries<X,Y> series){
        seriesList.add(series);
    }

    public void removeSeries(int index){
        seriesList.remove(index);
    }

    private void drawAxes(){
        xAxis.setAxisWidth(getPrefWidth() - 2*xPadding);
        xAxis.setAxisHeight(10);

        yAxis.setAxisWidth(10);
        yAxis.setAxisHeight(getPrefHeight() - 2*yPadding);

        // Set X axis position
        xAxis.setAxisX(getLayoutX() + yAxis.getAxisWidth() + xPadding);
        xAxis.setAxisY(getLayoutY() + yAxis.getAxisHeight() + yPadding);

        // Set Y axis position
        yAxis.setAxisY(xAxis.getAxisY());
        yAxis.setAxisX(xAxis.getAxisX());

        xAxis.redraw();
        yAxis.redraw();
    }

    public void redraw(){
        drawAxes();

        // Chart background
        chartBackground.setPrefWidth(getPrefWidth());
        chartBackground.setPrefHeight(getPrefHeight());
        chartBackground.setLayoutX(getLayoutX());
        chartBackground.setLayoutY(getLayoutY());

        /*
        // Chart plotting pane
        chartPlotPane.setLayoutX(xAxis.getAxisX());
        chartPlotPane.setLayoutY(yAxis.getAxisY() - yAxis.getAxisHeight());

        chartPlotPane.setPrefWidth(xAxis.getAxisWidth());
        chartPlotPane.setMaxWidth(xAxis.getAxisWidth());*/

        chartPlotPane.setPrefHeight(yAxis.getAxisHeight());
        chartPlotPane.setMaxHeight(yAxis.getAxisHeight());
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a simple code snippet trying to do what I explaining:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PaneTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane bgPane = new Pane();
        Pane pane1 = new Pane();
        Pane pane2 = new Pane();

        bgPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        pane1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        pane2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

        pane1.setLayoutX(0);
        pane1.setLayoutY(0);
        pane2.setLayoutX(100);
        pane2.setLayoutY(100);

        bgPane.getChildren().addAll(pane1, pane2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bgPane, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why your Pane Test doesn't display any panes*

A pane is automatically sized to fit its content.  If it has no content and no minimum size, then it has no size at all, so you won't see it.  If you set a minimum size for your panes, you will be able to see them, for example:

```
pane1.setMinSize(200, 200);
pane2.setMinSize(300, 300);
```

I did not try to debug the code in your custom XYChart, to determine why your lines don't show up there, my guess is the problem might not be related to z-order logic but may be related to some other code issue.

*Some Advice*

You've got a long way to go to complete your charting package.  If the inbuilt JavaFX charting package is not meeting your requirements, I suggest evaluating a 3rd party library such as [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) or [OrsonCharts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/), which can be used in JavaFX via the the [FXGraphics2D](http://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/) bridge.

Comment: Great! That was the issue. Nice didn't know about `FXGraphics2D` will give it a try cause you are right, is not that simply to create a chart library!