# Circle won't move position in JavaFX

Tags: java

I am creating a widget which so far has a battery monitor and clock. I tried to add a circle behind the battery monitor to make it look like the shape of a battery. I have tried to change the position values of the circle but it isn't moving.
the following picture shows what I am getting now and the intended effect

[image]

Here is my code for the circle:

```
                stack = new StackPane();
                Text text2 = new Text();
                Circle circle = new Circle(10, 10, 10, Color.BLACK);

                batteryBar = new ProgressBar();
                batteryBar.setPrefHeight(27);
                batteryBar.setId("battery");

                stack.getChildren().addAll(batteryBar, text2, circle);
                text2.setFont(new Font("Arial", 15));
                text2.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
                text2.setFill(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Have you tried moving it with `setX()` and `setY()` ?

Comment: I believe that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21124395/2988730) will help you (to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21118394/2988730)).

Answer (score 1):

You can Easily set the X and Y coordinates of the Circle with the methods `setX()` and `setY()`. You also might want to consider `setLayoutX()`and `setLayoutY()` which set the `x` and `y` coordinates relative to the `Layout`

Also Note that `StackPane` cannot be used here. You must use `Pane` for setting the `x` and `y` axis of the Circle.

This is because `StackPane` overrides all the `x` and `y` values with its own. To know more about this, check out this Stack-overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118394/explicitly-positioning-nodes-in-javafx)

Here would be your final Code :-

```
            pane= new Pane();
            Text text2 = new Text();
            Circle circle = new Circle(10, 10, 10, Color.BLACK);
            circle.setLayoutX(10);
            circle.setLayoutY(10);
            batteryBar = new ProgressBar();
            batteryBar.setPrefHeight(27);
            batteryBar.setId("battery");

            pane.getChildren().addAll(batteryBar, text2, circle);
            text2.setFont(new Font("Arial", 15));
            text2.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
            text2.setFill(Color.WHITE);
```