# Add a spot on JavaFx ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, javafx-8

I want the spot on `ImageView` where users click. I am getting the coordinates where user click but how to add the spot on that point?
Is it possible to add a spot on the specified coordinates? If yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Circle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html) or other [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html) for a spot. Add a new spot on every mouse click in the clicked position. Check this demo,

```
public class ImageViewSpotDemo extends Application {    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
        Pane root = new Pane();

        ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("file:src/path/image.png"));
        image.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {

            //A new spot
            Circle spot = new Circle(4);
            spot.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            spot.setCenterX(4.0f);
            spot.setCenterY(4.0f);

            double x = e.getSceneX() - 3;
            double y = e.getSceneY() - 3;

            spot.setLayoutX(x);
            spot.setLayoutY(y);

            root.getChildren().add(spot);
        });

        root.getChildren().add(image);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
}
```

> Note : Use the [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) layout as parent root for image-view and spots for positioning. Why? Check answer of @jewelsea on [Explicitly positioning nodes in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118394/explicitly-positioning-nodes-in-javafx).

Comment: plus 1  Thanks Bro... You save my day