# Javafx line connecting two circles in a stackpane

Tags: javafx

I'm able to display 2 co-ordinates(represented by 2 circles) over an image of fixed size in a Stackpane and now i'm trying to draw a line connecting the 2 circles. Although the line appears, it doesn't seem to be connecting the circles. I'm new to javafx & trying to create a debug tool to plot map data. So far my code looks something similar to below.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    Image img = new Image("some_image_of_730x730_size.jpg");
    ImageView view = new ImageView(img);

    Circle start = new Circle();
    start.setRadius(30);
    start.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
    start.setTranslateX(-365 + 340);
    start.setTranslateY(-365 + 630);

    Circle end = new Circle();
    end.setRadius(30);
    end.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
    end.setTranslateX(-365 + 400);
    end.setTranslateY(-365 + 120);

    Circle origin = new Circle();
    origin.setRadius(3);
    origin.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
    origin.setTranslateX(0);
    origin.setTranslateY(0);

    Line line = new Line();
    line.setStartX(-365 + 340);
    line.setStartY(-365 + 630);
    line.setEndX(-365 + 400);
    line.setEndY(-365 + 120);
    line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    root.getChildren().addAll(view, start, end, line, origin);

    Group group = new Group();
    group.getChildren().add(root);

    Scene scene  = new Scene(group, 730, 730, Color.ALICEBLUE);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Is this the correct way or am i missing something?

Comment: A stack pane will just center all its child nodes by default. Transformations (such as the translations you use on your circles) are applied to the child nodes after this layout is performed. So the line is simply centered in the stack pane. Try using a plain `Pane` instead of the stack pane (and you probably want to use `centerX` and `centerY` on the circles instead of `translateX` and `translateY`).

Comment: It worked! After changing it to plain Pane & by using the centerX and centerY for circles.

Comment: Also similar: [Explicitly positioning nodes in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118394/explicitly-positioning-nodes-in-javafx)