# Rectangle Position in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I can't seem to be able to position rectangles appropriately in the pane. Doing something as simple as

```
 StackPane layout = new StackPane();


 Rectangle r = new Rectangle( 0, 0, 30, 30);

 r.setLayoutX(0);
 r.setLayoutY(0);
 layout.getChildren().add(r);

 Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle( 40, 40, 30, 30);

 r1.setLayoutX(40);
 r1.setLayoutY(40);
 layout.getChildren().add(r1);

 primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
 primaryStage.show();
```

doesn't work and I don't undesrand why. I get a unique rectangle, centered and not the two rectangles I'm expecting.

Comment: Check this link May be help ful @Afunakwa

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html

Comment: You failed to tell us what that looks like and why that looks wrong to you.

Comment: Most layouts set `layoutX` and `layoutY` during a layout pass instead of keeping the position perviously assigned. You need to add information about `layout` to the question and describe the expected result and the result you get instead.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118394/explicitly-positioning-nodes-in-javafx). StackPane overrides previous positioning. Using Pane instead does the trick.